# Share one directory on Ubuntu computer with another Ubuntu computer

Tags: networking, samba

I would like to share folders on one computer with another. Both are Ubuntu.  I already have samba shares to Windows computers. Both are on the same network.

I am a bit confused on the various options that are available.  It seems some options such as NFS are oldish and less secure.  I would like to use the one that is most efficient / secure.

Thanks for directing me to the most current approach.

A guide a I follow would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already have samba shares because of Windows why not use those?

Comment: I do, I will.   I presume the client side is identical. You wouldn't have s guide I can follow for the server side please?

Comment: Easiest way is using Files > Other... Connect to server (use smb://......)

Comment: You're right. That is how I connect to Windows computers.